# How do I set Gnome as default DE if I am already using Cinnamon?

Tags: fedora, gnome, cinnamon, desktop-environment

I think (let's be clear maybe I am complete wrong) I have installed Gnome by running the following command:

```
yum groupinstall "GNOME"
```

Now I want to get rid of Cinammon and use Gnome by default but I can't get a way to do this. So far I have changed `/etc/sysconfig/desktop` from:

```
PREFERRED=/usr/bin/cinammon-session
DISPLAYMANAGER=/usr/sbin/lightdm
```

to:

```
PREFERRED=/usr/bin/gnome-session
DISPLAYMANAGER=/usr/sbin/lightdm
```

But doesn't work. I have installed `displaymanager` by running:

```
yum install system-switch-displaymanager
```

But I don't even know where this goes or what it does so I am stuck at this point.

How do I change to use Gnome by default and get rid of Cinnamon? Possibly uninstalling it complete?

Answer (score 2):

Although I think it can be changed by editing conf file, using the dropdown top-right of the lightdm login screen is easier.
gnome or gnome-session is not appeared in the dropdown?

Comment: I know this is your first answer. An answer to a "How to.. ?" question, should be precise, and include each required step to reach the objective (Including commands, images, etc). Try improving it please!

Comment: Thanks but I already saw such option and I don't like it. I want to set Gnome as default without need to go and change the dropdown and get rid complete of Cinnamon